# Not able to change icon on expand/collapse for current node

Tags: angular, ng-class

I am trying to change icon of my tree node when the tree node is expanded or collapsed. I am successfully able to change the icon, but the issue is that all the icon changes in the tree. I only want to change the icon f the node I have clicked.
My code is as below:

html file

```
<div class="container sidenav-tree">
  <ng-template #recursiveList let-files>
    <div *ngFor="let item of files">
      <div class="row node-item">
        <i
          data-toggle="collapse"
          attr.data-target="#{{item.reference}}"
          class="fa"
          [ngClass]="{'fa-angle-down': isExpanded, 'fa-angle-right': !isExpanded}"
          *ngIf="!(item.children.length===0)"
          (click)="isExpanded=!isExpanded"></i>
        {{item.name}}
      </div>
      <div id="{{item.reference}}" class="container collapse" *ngIf="!(item.children.length===0)">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: item.children }"></ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: files }"></ng-container>
</div>
```

and component file:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {BlogService} from '../../../../services/blog.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidenav.component.css'],
})
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {
  files: [];
  selectedFile: string;
  selectedPath: string;
  isExpanded = false;


  constructor(private blogService: BlogService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.blogService
      .getTreeNodes()
      .subscribe((files: []) => {
        console.log(files);
        this.files = files;
      });
  }

  nodeSelectEvent(event) {
    this.blogService.selectedNode.next(event.target.innerText);
  }
}
```

I want to keep my logic as much as possible in the ts file rather than component file. Please suggest the changes required in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this appears to be an arbitrary depth recursive tree the simplest thing would be to 
declare an object to model the file list you seem to be retrieving and have an attribute on that entity which describes whether it is expanded.

Something like a class added to your component

```
public export File{
  Name:string;
  isExanded:boolean;
}
```

Then I would change your files array to be

```
files:File[]
```

When you load the data in your subscribe you can either update your service to use a similar DTO object and return that collection or you can loop over the string list you get and create the File object instances. At this time you would initialize the isExanded option to false (unless you want to persist state server side).

I would then implement an event handler on the tree which updated the state of the current file

```
toggleFileState(item:File){
  item.isExpanded = !item.isExpanded;
}
```

Update your click event to call this event handler and pass the current item value. Also update your [ngClass] to reference the isExpanded property on the current item object instance

```
[ngClass]="{'fa-angle-down':item.isExpanded, 'fa-angle-right':!item.isExpanded'}"
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what exactly I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your boolean `isExpanded` is used for each item so if an item change the value to `true` all of your items state are changed.
You have to create a Map to store each item state and use it to determine whether the node is expanded or not.

I think you can use the `item.reference` for key in the Map to identify each item.

Something like that :

Component

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {BlogService} from '../../../../services/blog.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidenav.component.css'],
})
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {
  files: [];
  selectedFile: string;
  selectedPath: string;
  isExpanded = false;
  public itemsState = new Map<string, boolean>();


  constructor(private blogService: BlogService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.blogService
      .getTreeNodes()
      .subscribe((files: []) => {
        console.log(files);
        this.files = files;
        this.files.forEach(item => {
            // init all items to not expanded
            this.itemsState.set(item.reference, false);
        }
      });
  }

  nodeSelectEvent(event) {
    this.blogService.selectedNode.next(event.target.innerText);
  }
}
```

HTML :

```html
<div class="container sidenav-tree">
  <ng-template #recursiveList let-files>
    <div *ngFor="let item of files">
      <div class="row node-item">
        <i
          data-toggle="collapse"
          attr.data-target="#{{item.reference}}"
          class="fa"
          [ngClass]="{'fa-angle-down': itemsState.get(item.reference), 'fa-angle-right': !itemsState.get(item.reference)}"
          *ngIf="!(item.children.length===0)"
          (click)="isExpanded=!isExpanded"></i>
        {{item.name}}
      </div>
      <div id="{{item.reference}}" class="container collapse" *ngIf="!(item.children.length===0)">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: item.children }"></ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: files }"></ng-container>
</div>
```

The code is not tested, it's just to explain the principle

Comment: Isn't there a way that I can only change the class  of current icon only when clicked?

Comment: @VIBHORGOYAL I have update my answer with the correct "click" action